# Postgres looped table for logs

Tags: postgresql

Is it ok to make looped table for logs that has no need to live long using cycle sequence?

Only inconvenience I can see is that for log inserts you always need to add on conflic and maybe >second cycle insert will be slower because it's always be a conflict.

[Sandbox.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0738a/5)

```
create table foo (
    id int primary key,
    data text
);

CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq MINVALUE 1 maxvalue 3 cycle;
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('id_seq');


insert into foo (data) values ('1') on conflict (id) do update set data='1';
insert into foo (data) values ('2') on conflict (id) do update set data='2';
insert into foo (data) values ('3') on conflict (id) do update set data='3';
insert into foo (data) values ('4') on conflict (id) do update set data='4';
select* from foo order by id;
```

Or maybe there is easier way to do it? Like cleaning job that will run every year by postgres itself?

Requirements:

- many logs inserts
- reasonable overall table size
- logs don't need to live long, year is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems overly complicated and might not perform very well.

I would recommend using a partitioned table for logging. I would partition it by log time.

Then you can get rid of old entries by dropping a partition, which is very fast.

Answer (score 2):

It works, but I would suggest it is NOT a good design. The problem is your log reuses the id when it cycles. The the question then becomes "how many log entries will there be in a given time frame?" And what is the downside if you guess too small? I would add a date to the table and periodically run a delete for anything older than your time frame and let your sequence have full integer range. If however, you want to persist with a cyclic sequence you do not necessary need to change your statement. Instead of an insert statement, wrap it in a procedure.

```
create or replace procedure log_foo(p_data text) 
  language sql 
as $$
   insert into foo (data) values (p_data) 
       on conflict (id)
       do update set data=excluded.data 
$$;
```

or if your Postgres version does not have procedures or you want the ability to get the id:

```
create or replace function foo_log(p_data text) 
  returns integer
  language sql 
as $$
   insert into foo (data) values (p_data) 
       on conflict (id)
       do update set data=excluded.data 
       returning id;
$$;
```

See [full example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5f0b4bf66ce15abdf8aa6516c5afbbd1) here. Note the procedure and function as they are themselves no matter how you define the sequence. Also the insert itself need only change for the actual data value in 1 place, not 2.